# How can I make Packer ignore the splitright setting?

Tags: neovim, split

I have `splitright` set in my `init.lua` so that when I run `:vs`, the new split opens on the right. Using Neovim 0.5-HEAD, [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) follows this setting and opens its splits on the right. I would like these splits to open on the left instead.

I have tried `:leftabove PackerStatus`, `:topleft PackerStatus`, but it still opens on the right.

I also noticed that out of the different plugins I have tried so far, [nvim-tree](https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua), [nvim-dap-ui](https://github.com/rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui), and [VOoM](https://github.com/vim-voom/VOoM) all open their splits on the left, even if `splitright` is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass custom initialization parameters to the `packer.init()` call to configure this specific behavior. See [Custom Initialization](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim#custom-initialization) in the README.md for more details.

In your specific case, you can change `display.open_cmd`, which defaults to `'65vnew \\[packer\\]'`, to include a `leftabove` as a prefix.

Comment: I'm not very well versed in Lua, but I hope this is helpful to you... If it manages to solve your problem, feel free to [edit] this answer and add more details, such as the specific invocation you used and in which file you added it. Thanks!!!